# File system type and swap partition during Installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

First of all I’m a total newbie with Linux, and after another disappointment from Microsoft with failure to maintain backwards compatibility for my XP Applications I’m ready to give Linux with Wine a try.

About my system:
Out of the box Dell Vostro 200
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E7200 @ 2.53GHz x2, 64-bit
Memory: 2GB
Graphics: Intel G33 (integrated)

Please forgive me if this is repeat post, but after much research I’m a bit confused.

My questions pertain to the default installation for a standalone Linux system.

I did format the hard drive as NFTS with only one partition and did the standalone installation.

After the installation I noticed that my hard drive file system type had changed to Ext4 and there is now 3 partitions; 
Partition 1 is 158G Ext4
Partition 2 is 2.1G (not sure of the file system) 
Partition 3 (shown as Partition 5) is 2.1G swap

To me this indicates that the Ubuntu 14.04 installation reformatted the hard drive, changed the file systems and partitioned the hard drive. After the fact my research showed that this is the default configuration for a standalone Linux system.

Question 1)
I’m fine with and actually prefer this. But does this mean I could have save ~1 hour by not formatting the hard drive?

Question 2)
Does this mean my linux-swap is fully configured and I can avoid using Gparted?

Question 3)
Where is the other two partitions, and why did the installation use 1,2 and 5?

Thanks

Comment: Which other partitions?

Comment: your questions are clear but the information you provided is not quite clear it would be helpful if you post a screen shot of your partitions in Gparted. Gparted is a useful tool its better to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you could simply install Ubuntu.

2) Yes, swap is on and you can simply use the system.

3) The partition 2 is extended partition that allows to have over 4 partitions on MBR drive. Every partition in extended partition (called "logical") has the number bigger than 4 (since numbers 1-4 are reserved to primary partitions (extended is counted as primary)). Your swap is inside the extended partition.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you waste ~1 hour of your life
2) Yes
3) You only have real 2 partitions. Partition 3 is inside the partition 2